# Best-effort (max|min)imisation in Z3 optimisations

Tags: optimization, z3, smt

I am interested in Z3 giving me a model and at the same time I would be happy if it tried to take an objective function into account as a heuristic, but I don't want to pay the performance penalty of finding the actual (max|min)imum.

Is this possible in Z3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already possible in Z3 with soft time outs, see this answer: [Z3 Time Restricted Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866753/z3-time-restricted-optimization)

The way to achieve what you want is to use incremental solving:

- Assert all your hard constraints. (i.e., those that need to be satisfied)
- Do a `check-sat` and get the model
- Assert all your "optimization" constraints.
- Use a soft-time out, as described here: [Z3 Time Restricted Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866753/z3-time-restricted-optimization)

In the last step, you can adjust how much you want to wait, i.e., the penalty you are willing to pay.

*Related note*: You might also want to play with soft-constraints, which the solver can "satisfy" optionally, incurring penalties if it doesn't. Perhaps that's more appropriate for your use case. See here on how to do that: https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/optimization#h23

Comment: Uuh, I stand corrected! I'll try this function too, thanks. How to set soft timeouts with smtlib syntax? I don't understand why you mention assert soft only, does it not work with standard objectives?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Quite right; I think it should work with regular constraints as well. See my edited answer.